# How do I 'grep' for the longest chain of lines matching a regexp

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'm running a program that outputs lines like these (simplified):

```
A
E
E
R
E
```

etc... And I'm trying to find the longest occurrence of the letter code E without something else in between. I suspect the easiest way would be to try looking for N consecutive where I try a couple descending values for N but I'm not sure how to do a specific case, say 3 consecutive E lines. Is this easy with a sed command? I thought of awk pattern range but it allows for anything in between..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using existing Unix tool set...

```
uniq -c file | sort -k2 -k1,1nr | awk '/E/{print $1;exit}'
```

`uniq` will give you the counts of sequences, `sort` by names and counts (in reverse order) so that highest run count will appear on top.  Let `awk` pick the highest sequence length which is the first by design.

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
BEGIN { currCount = maxCount = 0;}
$0 == "E" { currCount++;
            if(maxCount < currCount) {maxCount=currCount; line=NR;}
            next
          }

       { currCount=0; }

END { print "max sequence is " maxCount " ending at line " line }
```

if the line must match the pattern instead of equal exactly the string, use of `/E/` instead of `$0 == "E"`

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
program | perl -lne '
               if (/E/) { $c++ }
                  else  { $c = 0 }
               $m = $c if $m < $c;
               }{
               print $m'
```

`$m` remembers the maximal count `$c` which is incremented for each E and set to 0 for each non-E.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ uniq -c file | awk '/E/&&($1>m){m=$1} END{print m+0}'
2
```